# Proving that a subset is closed if a sequence of points is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm battling with a proof in my book regarding proving that a subset $S$ is closed iff the sequence of points $p_1, p_2, ...$ converges and

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n \in S$$

The first case is explained in the picture attached. My question: How is this a proof by contradiction? As far as I can see. This proves that there exists an open ball in the complement of $S$ that contains $p$ and $p_n$.

My apologies for the orientation.

[image]

Comment: I think you have, first of all, not yet grasped the statement of the theorem. Is it indeed the case the statement (which you have not included) really says "the sequence"? Can't you orient your camera/phone appropriately when you take a picture? Is this your homework?

Comment: Unfortunately, if I had, I would not be able to include the proof provided. And no.

Comment: You could possibly use tex to add the statement of the theorem. The current statement, as given in your question, seems incorrect or incomplete, so it is not clear what the proof you enclose is supposed to prove. I think the statement might say something along the lines "for **every** convergent sequence $p_n$ of points in $S$", etc.

Comment: I apologize for my supposed flippancy, as I am using an iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a proof by contradiction because it sound like: "assume your proposition is not true, then we have a contradiction". The contradiction here is that $p_n$ belongs to the complement of $S$, which can't be true because $(p_n)$ was a succession of points of $S$. The contradiction comes from having assumed that $p \notin S$ then $p\in S$.

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence.

Comment: When you deal with contradiction proofs you use this fact: if something leads to a contradiction, then it's false. In this case assuming that p doesn't belong to S leads to a contradiction: it must be false that p doesn't belong to S. The same way to say so is that p belongs to S

Comment: Don't they make the assumption that $p$ is in the complement of $S$ in the beginning? I'm not sure if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: Well, the assumption they make is that $p \notin S$, but it is exactly the same to say that p belongs to the complement of S: by definition the elements of the complement of S are those not belonging to S

Comment: Very good! I understand it now! Thank you for clarifying this problem for me!

Comment: the contradiction is that $p_n\in S$ for all $n$, yet $p_n\notin S$ for $n>N$. It is not about $p$, it is about $p_n$ for $n>N$. (But you said you understand it, which makes me feel puzzled, since I think in order to understand it, you need to first look at the $p_n$ for $n>N$. Then you get a contradiction, $p_n$ both in $S$ and not, for $n>N$. This contradictions shows you the initial assumption $p\notin S$ was wrong. Conclusion, $p\in S.)